# Is an OTP alone useful for a hacker?

Tags: malware, one-time-password

Further, does an unused OTP expire by itself? i.e in regards to digital banking - in case a hacker accesses your SMS's through malware or other means.

Comment: Depends on whether a standard is used. If you're talking about something like TOTP, a code is only valid for a minute or so. Companies who implement this manually (e.g. using SMS, which should be avoided) are free to choose their own timeout.

Comment: Thank you. Someone accessed my phone thru malware. In my SMS's, were a few messages from my bank that read: "Your password to spend X USD on 22/3 from your spotify office with your card: (an 8 digits/letters code). Please do not share with anyone." Now the issue is, I am afraid that the hacker could use this code (which seems to have been OTP, I do not remember since I had a head injury). My bank account is closed, and these SMS's were from 3 years ago or so. So I'm wondering if they are of any use on their own - without my credit card number which the hacker doesn't have

Comment: This last comment is really important context. No, someone getting those codes will do nothing. I'm more concerned about the hacker who has access to the rest of your phone, like your emails, etc...

Comment: Thank you Schroeder. Well, here is why I think my device has been hacked. I was typing the website address of a popular site, but instead of typing .com I typed .co and it redirected me to another page and downloaded a malware file called usd,jared-don[.]com. I was wondering if any information is available on the nature and functions of this malware, since Googling it did not produce any results. Whether or not it is spyware, adware, etc. for example or just a simple browser hijacker. Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who provides OTP. If the application is designed / implemented badly, it can accept OTPs without expiration. If the application is designed / implemented correctly, it will have expiration time for each OTP.

Comment: Thanks. Is an OTP alone, by itself, sufficient for a hacker to benefit from, or is credit card info needed?

Comment: @SamuelP: 1) *OTP alone* does not exist. It always exist in connection with the system where it is intended to be used. As I said, if the application is designed badly, it can allow expiration period 1 week or 1 month, or no expiration at all. Then an attacker can of course use this OTP. If the application designed correctly, then OTP expires in a short time. If an attacker gets access to OTP when it is expired, then there is no risk.

Comment: @SamuelP: 2) Digital banking again depends on implementation. Normally good implementation does need credit card at all and uses other mechanisms for authentication. If this does not answer your question, provide more details in your question.

Comment: Thanks sir. in a nutshell someone accessed my phone thru malware. In my SMS's, were a few messages from my bank that read: "Your password to spend X USD on 22/3 from your spotify office with your card: (an 8 digits/letters code). Please do not share with anyone." 
Now the issue is, I am afraid that the hacker could use this code (which seems to have been OTP, I do not remember since I had a head injury). 
My bank account is closed, and these SMS's were from 3 years ago or so. So I'm wondering if they are of any use on their own - without my credit card number which the hacker doesn't have

Comment: I have messaged the bank, but no reply unfortunately.

Comment: Sir, please tell me if more info is needed.

Comment: If SMS is 3 years old, you don't need to worry. If you think there is malware, reset your phone.

Comment: Thanks much. My concern is whether this OTP expires or not (I've contacted the bank, no reply) - and if this OTP is usable alone by itself, how useful it is to the hacker. The SMS said "Your password to spend X USD on specific date from your Spotify Office with your card (password here, 8 digits) Please do not share with anyone". My concern would be if that person were able to transfer that money to their account or something. Though, the SMS specifically specifies "Your spotify office". Lastly, my bank account has been closed since then - I'm wondering if the money was stored on spotify/sth

Answer (score 1):

The best practices for an OTP are that it be short-lived (even if not used) and single-use (thus, *One-Time* Password). However, not all sites follow these best practices.

Additionally, there's the question of whether an OTP is usable as a single credential, or if it's only usable in combination with some other authentication factor (traditional password, biometric, etc.). Some sites and services - even very security-focused ones, like Signal - use SMS OTPs as single factors by default; on such sites and services, the OTP can be used to gain full access (although with Signal in particular, it will warn everybody that your "safety number" has changed). In some cases, OTPs alone may be used as a limited credential, useful for some operations but not all. On others, the OTP is useless by itself and can only be used in combination with the other credential, in which case the attacker probably can't make much use of it even if the OTP did not expire / is multiple use.

As such, there's no clean-cut way to answer your question. It depends on the issuer of the OTP, whether that OTP has been used (and whether the issuer enforces single-use), how long ago it was issued (and whether the issuer enforces expiration), and what the issuer allows OTPs to be used for (full credential, limited credential, or second-factor only) plus whether the attacker has knowledge of any other authentication secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from whether if an OTP expires. It also depends on what right is granted using the OTP. Some services limit the use of OTP for read only operations. Some limit actions like changing the password, which it requires you to actually login with your password or reset it.

However, there are services that don't discriminate against the OTP and treat it as a full-blown credential. In this case, the OTP is more valuable to the hackers and they might be able to do more harm.

For example, some banks limit OTP privilege to view-only, which means you can only check your account balance but not transfer money.

If you want to transfer money, you'll have to use one of those banking access card readers or other MFA devices.

Comment: Thank you very much. In e-banking, is an OTP a full blown credential? (in spotify purchases for example)

Comment: It really depends on your bank. For example, my bank , UBS Switzerland, limits OTP to read only operation. So you can only check your account balance but not transfer money.

Comment: Thanks sir. I have messaged my old bank but they have not replied yet. Until then, is there a way I can know? Someone accessed my phone thru malware. In my SMS's, were a few messages from my bank that read: "Your password to spend X USD on 22/3 from your spotify office with your card: (an 8 digits/letters code). Please do not share with anyone." Now the issue is, I am afraid that the hacker could use this code (which seems to have been OTP, I do not remember since I had a head injury). My bank account is closed, and these SMS's were from 3 years ago or so.

Comment: PS: is the OTP sent every time you want to login? And is it alone by itself sufficient for a login, without any expiry date whatsoever? Thanks

Comment: The provider of OTP will inform you about the expiry time usually. However, we can be sure that OTP can only be used one time as the name suggested.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have contacted the old bank, but have received no reply. The thing is, in short, that my bank account since then has been closed. The SMS was sent 3 years ago or so. My concern is whether or not a hacker who gains the OTP and knows what site is being used, can actually transfer the money to somewhere else. The SMS reads as follows: "Your password to spend X USD on 22/3 from your spotify office with your card: (an 8 digits/letters code). Please do not share with anyone."

Comment: The possibility is really low. As most of the OTP has an expiry time.